# Creating menu with skewed blocks and diamond in the center

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have big trouble in creating such thing. Here you can see what I'm working on:
https://jsfiddle.net/8ksxgh5o/

Overall idea is to look it like on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTs6Q.jpg).

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="offer-boxes">
  <div class="offer-box-title">
    <h2>SOME <strong>TEXT</strong></h2></div>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-1 left">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-2 right">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-3 right">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-4 left">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.offer-boxes {
  position: relative;
  height: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.offer-button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1d1d1b;
}

.offer-button>h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.offer-box-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.offer-box-title>h2>strong {
  display: block;
}

.offer-button.left {
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
}

.offer-button.left>h3,
.offer-button.left>img {
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: skew(20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.offer-button.right {
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
}

.offer-button.right>h3,
.offer-button.right>img {
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.offer-1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 54.5%;
  top: 0;
}

.offer-1::before {
  content: "";
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  background-image: url('http://www.i-love-cats.com/images/2015/04/12/cat-wallpaper-38.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
}

.offer-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 54.5%;
  top: 0;
}

.offer-2::before {
  content: "";
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  background-image: url('http://www.i-love-cats.com/images/2015/04/12/cat-wallpaper-38.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
}

.offer-3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 54.5%;
  top: 450px;
}

.offer-3::before {
  content: "";
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  background-image: url('http://www.i-love-cats.com/images/2015/04/12/cat-wallpaper-38.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
}

.offer-4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 54.5%;
  top: 450px;
}

.offer-4::before {
  content: "";
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  background-image: url('http://www.i-love-cats.com/images/2015/04/12/cat-wallpaper-38.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  -ms-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

Can anyone help me with some tips? I have barely any control over that skewed elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very much possible to achieve the effect that you are looking for using CSS skew transforms. We just need to give the correct `transform-origin` setting to it. By making `.offer-box-title` take entire height and width of parent, positioning it absolutely with respect to parent, the text can also be made to appear at the center. Looking at the screenshot, the text inside the diamond seems to be short and not dynamic, hence this approach wouldn't run into overflow problems.

The output is responsive (as you can see by opening the snippet output in full page mode) and `hover` effect is also restricted to the shapes (you can see this by hovering each shape including diamond).

I have also added some inline comments into the snippet for extra explanation.

```css
.offer-boxes {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;  /* to demonstrate responsiveness */
  min-height: 450px;  /* just for demo as snippet run window is too small */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.offer-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;  /* to avoid jagged edges due to transform */
}
.offer-button > h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.offer-button::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/5);
  background-position: right;
}  
.offer-box-title {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.offer-box-title > h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-75%);
  text-align: center;
}
.offer-1, .offer-2 {
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;  /* the space between the top and bottom blocks */
}
.offer-3, .offer-4 {
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid white;  /* the space between the top and bottom blocks */
}
.offer-1 {
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
.offer-2 {
  transform: skewX(15deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.offer-3 {
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
.offer-4 {
  transform: skewX(15deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
.left {
  left: 0;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
}

/* the transform on parent affects child and so has to be reversed, the translation is to get it centered */
.offer-1 > h3 {
  transform: skewX(15deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
.offer-2 > h3 {
  transform: skewX(-15deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.offer-3 > h3 {
  transform: skewX(15deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
.offer-4 > h3 {
  transform: skewX(-15deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}

/* similar to the h3, the pseudo element is also actually a child and so transform should be reversed */
.offer-1:before{
  transform: skew(15deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
.offer-2:before{
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.offer-3:before{
  transform: skew(15deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
.offer-4:before{
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Just for demo */

a[class^="offer"]:hover:before,
.offer-box-title:hover {
  background: crimson;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-boxes">
  <div class="offer-box-title">
    <h2>SOME<br><strong>TEXT</strong></h2>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-1 left">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-2 right">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-3 right">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-4 left">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:
I realised an issue with this technique - in that if you hover over the diamond pieces it will count as hover for that corner link which might not be ideal for your case - however I hope the concept of using pseudo-triangles help you here! Please let me know if you would like me to update the fiddle to fix this**

As the center diamond is completely white, I would actually be more inclined to use pseudo elements and CSS triangle to replicate this, and absolutely positioning them to each of the offer-box corners.

https://jsfiddle.net/qnb08s3s/

And the triangle generator that I find very helpful:
http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.offer-boxes {
  position:relative;
}
.offer-boxes:after {
  display:table;
  content:"";
  clear:both;
}
.offer-box-title {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  height:90px;
  width:120px;
  margin-left:-60px;
  margin-top:-45px;
  background:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1;
}
.offer-button {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:250px;
  background: url('http://www.i-love-cats.com/images/2015/04/12/cat-wallpaper-38.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.offer-button h3 {
  max-width:90%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.offer-button:after {
  content:"";
  width:1px;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.offer-button:before {
  content:"";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  position:absolute;
}
.offer-1:before {
  border-width: 0 0 200px 100px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
.offer-2:before {
  border-width: 200px 0 0 100px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
.offer-3:before {
  border-width: 0 100px 200px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
.offer-4:before {
  border-width: 200px 100px 0 0;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-boxes">
  <div class="offer-box-title">
    <h2>SOME <strong>TEXT</strong></h2></div>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-1 left">
    <h3>Marketing</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-2 right">
    <h3>PR Consulting</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-3 right">
    <h3>Projekty Unijne</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="offer-button offer-4 left">
    <h3>Multimedia</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very cool and that hover over diamond pieces isnt an issue. If I understand right, the border-size have to be in pixels so I have to set fixed size for the 4 blocks? I will test it tommorow and will let you know if it worked.

Comment: The triangles can also be done with percentages - https://jsfiddle.net/3HG6d/2202/ but you have to adjust the border widths, and the percentages to change the angles! If you don't need it to be responsive and you know the image dimensions then easiest to keep to PX sizes!

Answer (score 0):

#### NOTE: `clip-path` is [not well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). Until it is, I do *not* recommend using the techniques in this answer in a production environment.

The skew is going to be unruly. `clip-path` makes things *so* much easier:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: white;
clip-path: polygon(50% 10%, 60% 50%, 50% 90%, 40% 50%);
```

This makes the central element cover the whole screen with a white background color, the clips it back to a diamond shape.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.container .center {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 10%, 60% 50%, 50% 90%, 40% 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 10%, 60% 50%, 50% 90%, 40% 50%);
}
.container .image {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)), url("http://lorempixel.com/g/800/600/");
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.container .image a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">SOME TEXT</div>
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#">TITLE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#">TITLE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#">TITLE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#">TITLE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you bassicaly this makes 4 blocks and 'cover' them with clipped element? I tried that with png image but then block underneath aren't clickable where png is overlaping.

Comment: @Gekiyaku Yes, that's what I'm doing, but the CSS clip still allows you to click the elements that the clipping reveals. Transparency on images, however doesn't work that way.